# Inconsistency with flex-grow between Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

If I add `height: 100%`, the following code works in Chrome, but does not work in Safari. I'm attempting to have the `#view` expand to fill the whole viewport.

I am puzzled why `#main`'s height will be 100% even if I don't add it in `style`. Why is this the case?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#work-interface {
  height: 100%;
}

#main {
}

#view {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="work-interface" class="container-fluid d-flex">
    <div class="row flex-grow">
        <div id="main" class="col-md-9 d-flex flex-column">
            <div id="view" class="flex-grow">
                <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by *fails*? What fails, in particular?

Comment: Meaning it does not expand to fill the screen. The flex-grow property is supposed to do so and it does in Chrome but not Safari which puzzles me.

Comment: I've edited your question to *hopefully* simplify your question for future readers. I'm by no means an expert in CSS, so if I've omitted some important information, feel free to roll back my edit, or include any relevant details.